# Unable to disable all fields of a ms-access userform on load

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, userform

I have lots of controls on my userform and I want to disable all of them on load except for "login button" and "Shift Date" textbox, so i am using the code below:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Call GetValues
Me.WlcmLabel.Caption = "Hi " + GetUserName + " ! "

Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    ctrl.Enabled = False
Next
Me.ShiftDate.Enabled = True
Me.LoginBtn.Enabled = True
Set ctrl = Nothing
End Sub
```

but this gives me an error on load saying "object does not support this property or method."

all the controls will get enabled as soon as the user clicks on login button.

What would be the mistake in my code ?

Please ask if any other information required.
Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try locking the control instead.  I have used the locked property below, but I use the tag property of each control to identify it as lockable.  So the controls you don't want to lock will not get anything in the tag property, and therefore will not lock.  For your application, you could flip the logic since you only want leave the two controls unlocked.

```
For Each ctlCurr In Me.Controls
        If ctlCurr.Tag = "Lockable" Then
        ctlCurr.Locked = True
        End If
Next
```

Comment: Can you show your revised code?  I lock controls like this frequently and do you have your issue.  Hmmm...

Comment: sure, here is the code i am using in load event,
`Dim ctlCurr As Control

For Each ctlCurr In Me.Controls
        If ctlCurr.Tag = "Lockable" Then
        ctlCurr.Locked = True
        End If
Next

    Me.ShiftDate.Enabled = True
    Me.LoginBtn.Enabled = True `

Comment: Did you set the Tag property to Locked for all of the controls except LoginBtn and ShiftDate?

Comment: Okay I got it, I its working now. But I am still able to click inside the txtbox, It does not let the user to type however. But i want to let user notice that the fields are disabled and they can only click one button and a txtbox, what if I just replace "ctlCurr.Locked = True" with "ctlCurr.Enabled= True" ?

Comment: Yes, that should work except I think you want Enabled = False.  I just tried that, and the disabled controls are gray and will not allow the user to go into the field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161762/discussion-between-kensquare-and-shiv-chhabra).

Comment: Yes it has fixed the issue, they are all disabled now, thanks man. great work !!

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable label control that's why that error is coming. You have to check the type of control.

```
 For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    With ctrl
     a = TypeName(ctrl)
    Select Case .ControlType

        Case acLabel

        Case acEmptyCell

        Case Else
            ctrl.Enabled = False
    End Select
    End With


 Next ctrl
```

Apply disable only when it's not label.

Comment: thanks for clarification on this, well it did not give any error but also did not disable anything. what to do ?

Comment: @shivchhabra   
I have edited the above answer. Check above code and tell me if it didn't work.